# Django Rest Framework: Unclear error message

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-rest-framework

my **views.py**:

```
class user_password(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    authentication_classes = ([JSONWebTokenAuthentication])
    serializer_class = user_password_serializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return User.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)
```

But I'm getting this when running it:

> AssertionError: Expected view user_password to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly.

I know the serializer is okay because when I use a different type of View for the same thing. It works:

```
class user_password(APIView):

    authentication_classes = ([JSONWebTokenAuthentication])

    def put(self, request, format=None):

        serializer = user_password_serializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            if request.user.check_password(serializer.validated_data[
                                                'old_password']):
                request.user.set_password(serializer.validated_data[
                                          'new_password'])
                request.user.save()

                return Response({'success': True,
                                'result': serializer.validated_data},
                                status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            else:
                    return Response({'success': False,
                                    'result': "credential mismatch"},
                                    status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)


        return Response({'success': False,
                        'result': serializer.errors},
                        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I do not wish to change the way an endpoint is constructed. I do have a JWT authenticated call, and I wish /user/password would simply be able to PUT the 'old password' and 'new password' into that very same user.

What am I doing wrong in my `generics.UpdateAPIView` class? what is that `.lookup_field` it's talking about?

Comment: Can you share the `urls.py` for the view?

Comment: `url(r'^user/password/$', views.user_password.as_view()),` and I really don't want to have a `/{user_id}/` in my URL. my app is JWT based, the user is already recognized through the JWT token. I just want an endpoint to change the users password, same user matching the JWT token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.lookup_feild` is the field (capture group) the `UpdateAPIView` expects in your url pattern (`pk` by default), like:

```
r'^user/(?P<pk>\d+)/password/?$'
```

However, you should be able to override [`get_object`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#get_objectself) instead of `get_queryset` and it should work without any changes to the url.

```
class user_password(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    authentication_classes = ([JSONWebTokenAuthentication])
    serializer_class = user_password_serializer

    def get_object(self):
        return User.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)
```

Also, simply returning `self.request.user` will work just fine (I don't know how exactly JWT authentication implemented in your project, but most of the time Django pulls the user model in `request.user` anyway).

Comment: with your suggestion `get_object(self)` override I'm getting a `.update() must be implemented.` error.

Comment: @Gdalia Yea, you need an update method on your *serializer* class. If you're having problems with that - add your serializer to the question and ping me